# What is a safe way to extract a value from a string without using regex

Tags: scala

I have a string that looks like this:

```
val s = "123 some address (Latitude 100, Longitude 500)"
```

I just want to grab the text inside of the brackets.
What would be a safe way to do this without getting index out of bounds errors?

I can do this:

```
s.substring(s.indexOf("(") + 1)   // and then remove the last character
```

The value will always be in the string, that is guaranteed.

Just looking for alternative ways to make this code seem very readable and obvious, and safe from  throwing exceptions.

Comment: I would suggest moving the code to some separate method with readable name.

Comment: Why the requirement to not use regex? That's arguably the best solution here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't quite understand why you are excluding regex solutions. They are the perfect solution for this problem:

```scala
final val regex = raw"\(([^)]*)\)".r.unanchored
val coord = s match
  case regex(coord) => coord
```

Alternatively, you could use a string pattern:

```scala
val coord = s match
  case s"$_($coord)$_" => coord
```

[Scastie link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JoergWMittag/6lmx788VSdqK3CTpyQycCg/10)

Comment: Thanks for this solution.  I was totally unaware of the alternative match case using the string pattern.  I learned something new!!

Answer (score 2):

How about `dropWhile`:

```
scala> s.dropWhile(_ != '(').tail.takeWhile(_ != ')')
val res0: String = Latitude 100, Longitude 500
```